# Who owns the Infinity Stones and where did they come from?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, infinity-stones

Given that the Infinity Stones are just lying around before they have been found and kept away, who originally created and owns them? Is there any MCU or comics answer?

Comment: “Given that the Infinity Stones are just lying around before they have been found” — the Tesseract wasn’t just lying around! It was hidden in a church!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Yeah, but it was just lying there.

Comment: @DCShannon: the MCU does I think suffer from the absence of Mexican Jumping Infinity Stones.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### The MCU answer

The Infinity Stones formed naturally, from "singularities" that were present at the beginning of the universe. From the *Guardians of the Galaxy*  transcript:

> **The Collector**: Oh, my new friends. Before creation itself, there were
>   six singularities. [he uses a device to unlock and open the orb] Then
>   the universe exploded into existence, and the remnants of these
>   systems were forged into concentrated ingots. Infinity Stones. These
>   stones, it seems, can only be brandished by beings of extraordinary
>   strength. Observe. [he shows them the giant beings that use the
>   Infinity Stones as weapons] These carriers can use the stone to mow
>   down entire civilizations like wheat in a field.

As such, the Infinity Stones basically existed before the universe, and as such did not have creators. On the other hand, it is possible that "forged" is meant more literally and the stones *as they are now* have creators. As indicated in Aogiri's answer, the cosmic entities Death, Infinity, Entropy, and Eternity are likely the ones who who put the singularities into their modern form.

### The comics answer

The Infinity Gems (not Stones) are the remnants of Nemesis, an extremely powerful cosmic entity.

[image: From Thanos Quest #2]

When Nemesis grew lonely, it committed suicide. In doing so, it gave birth to the universe.<sup>1</sup> The Infinity Gems are what remains of this entity's essentially limitless power. In the comics, there is another gem, Ego, which contains the core of Nemesis's consciousness. If it were ever united with the other six, Nemesis would be reborn.<sup>2</sup>. So one can think of Nemesis as the original creator or owner of the Infinity Gems.

<sup><sub>1: Note that this origin is undoubtedly inconsistent with half a  dozen other Marvel multiverse origin stories.</sub></sup>

<sup><sub>2: This has of course happened.</sub></sup>

Comment: Very well said. Thanks for answering! :)

Comment: The 2 part answer doesn't need to be divided as you have it. The MCU's story doesn't contradict the comic's ^.^ The gems were created when Nemesis died which then created the universe meaning that the gems existed before the universe. Also, since different people have different perspectives and level of knowledge it's not unlikely that the Collector was just telling the story that he knew rather than the truth which we don't know yet.

Comment: @Durakken - I thought about putting that in, but I feel it is better to keep them separate. The MCU and comics have often diverged, and so it is difficult to say how closely the MCU version follows the comics. In the case of the comics, we know a great deal more.

Comment: I just learned that in the MCU, the Infinity Stones were created by the four entities that are displayed in the walls of the Temple Wall in Morag: Entropy, Infinity, Death, and Eternity. [link here](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Cosmic_Entities#History)

Comment: The original entity may have been a Boltzmann brain: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_brain

Answer (score 13):

**In the MCU**, [wikia](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Cosmic_Entities#History) mentioned that the Infinity Stones were created by the Cosmic Entities from the six singularities that @Adamant (above answer) mentioned.

> Before the Universe began, six singularities existed. Sometime after the Universe came into existence, these were formed into the six Infinity Stones by the [Cosmic Entities](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Cosmic_Entities).

They are Entropy, Infinity, Death, and Eternity, and they can be seen in the walls of the Temple Vault on Morag in *Guardians of the Galaxy (2014)* (See images below).

**As for the comics**, I must say @Adamant answered the lot of it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The guy in the carving on the upper right looks suspiciously like Captain America. Lower right looks like Iron Man. I wonder if there is going to be some time travelling in the Avengers future? (Past?)

Comment: Man, I hope not @Shane, the last thing we need is to make the MCU muddled with time travel crap.

Comment: @Shane I was actually thinking the upper right looks like vision.

Comment: Well,  there *is*  a Time Stone.

Comment: I don't think any of those figures look like any of the Avengers. Also, the wiki cites the book [The Art of Guaridans of the Galaxy](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/The_Art_of_Guardians_of_the_Galaxy) as its source for this information.

Comment: Do you want to vote on the synonyms for [tag:infinity-stones]? You have enough reputation in the tag.

Comment: There are four of them. It's the Fantastic Four. They existed in the universe before the MCU which is why they aren't in the MCU.

Comment: Actually, if they're supposed to match their comics representations then upper right is most likely Eternity. Lower right would be Infinity. I don't remember an Entropy. https://www.marvel.com/characters/eternity